# Selenium in python - initializing the driver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have downloaded the necessary drivers for using selenium in chrome. This is the code I am using:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
```

When I am initialising the variable driver itself, a chrome page is opened. I do not want that to happen. I want to open a chrome page only when I use the driver.get() method. How do I do it?

Answer (score -1):

The driver will open chrome by default.

If you want to open the chrome by *driver.get()* method then use the code below:

**Try this:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')

driver.get(url='http://www.facebook.com')
```

Pass the url in *driver.get()*